# How to deal with # sign smartly in the start of the csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

this question seems to be answer but in a different manner. I want to skip the first two lines because they are just description and in 3rd line I want to neglect the # sign but no the data because I want to read and compare this data as columns names.

```
# some description here
# 1 is for good , 2 is bad and 3 for worse
# 0 temp_data 1 temp_flow  2 temp_record 3 temp_all
```

For skip lines I know I can do something like this

```
with open('kami.txt') as f:
lines_after_2 = f.readlines()[2:]
```

and to read a file with respective line number or everyline

```
def read_data(data):
with open(data, 'rb') as f:
    data = [row for row in csv.reader(f.readlines())]
return data
```

and to do unit testing on columns names I do this

```
 def test_csv_read_data_headers(self):
    self.assertEqual(
        read_data(self.data)[0],
        ['temp_data 1 temp_flow  2 temp_record 3 temp_all']
        )
```

but as I am doing some unit testing and therefore I want to neglect # sign in 3rd line and not the rest of the data which is this.

```
temp_data 1 temp_flow  2 temp_record 3 temp_all
```

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanx alot

Answer (score 0):

did you try pandas ?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("kami.txt", header=None, skiprows = 2, names = [temp_data,
temp_flow, temp_record, temp_all])
```